# Limit session per User - ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, session-cookies

I am using mongoDB as a Database and passportjs for authentication.

I want to have a maximum of 3 sessions per user.

For that, I created a *sessionCount* field on my mongo document.

everytime the user logs in, I increment the count and when they log out, I decrement.

But the problem arises when the session auto-expires. The session count stays the same.

Q. is there any way to "detect" session expiration so that I could decrement that *sessionCount* field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    I am also facing the same kind of issue I solve it by using this way->
    


    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        //Checking previously set cookie (if there is one)
        var session = JSON.parse(req.cookies['session'] || '');
        if (session && new Date(session.expires) < new Date()) {
            // decrement the count
        }
        next();
    });
```